# How to select specific index in NSMutableArray and stored in nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have developed simple app that stores name and id of student into NSMutableArray  by using NSDictionary and I want to get names only after stored in NSMutableArray and than store into NSArray

**Here my simple code**

```
NSDictionary *student1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"key1", @"id",
                          @"Joe", @"name",
                          nil];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:student1, nil];
```

please help me how to solve this.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want  to select specific index(names only)  in NSMutableArray and stored in nsarray

Comment: It may help if you provide an example of what you're looking for. Do you want to know the what index a name is stored within the array of dictionaries when searching by name?

Comment: I am looking for to get specific index's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *student1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"key1", @"id",
                          @"Joe", @"name",
                          nil];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:student1, nil];

NSMutableArray *mArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *student in array) {
    [mArr addObject:[student objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
NSArray *arr = mArr;
NSLog(@"%@",arr);    //OUTPUT: (Joe)
```

Comment: I tried but it displays the fallowing : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Please show your code, and tell me in which line it is getting crash... The error message says that you're trying to insert a object which is nil

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're looking for the name at a specific index (Objective-c)

```
NSDictionary *student = array[SPECIFIC_INDEX];

NSString *name = student[@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your questions assuming that you have an array of student dictionaries (id and name) and trying to filter the array with respect to name.

```
for dic in array as! [NSDictionary] {
   if dic.objectForKey("name") as! String == "searchyournamehere"
   {
        //name matched perform your operation here
   }
}
```

Drawback : since multiple student may have same name it is a good practice to filter the array with respect to id(Assuming it as unique), nevertheless you are searching for multiple student with same name the above code will help.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @Melebius, updated the answer, hope it clarifies the idea now